# Can't visualize UIBezierPath in Playground

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I remember there was a time that I can visualize a bezier path in Xcode Playground, but with the latest version (8.3.1) that ability is gone?

```
import UIKit

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: .zero)
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
```

All I see is how many elements the path has:

[image]

Anyone has the same issue with Playground in Xcode 8.3.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say this is a bug in Xcode 8.3. It gave me the same result in Xcode 8.3. I just tried your code in Xcode 8.2.1 and it draws a line in the quick look window.

[image: image of line in the quick look window]

This is something that should be filed as a bug report to Apple.

In the meantime, either use an older version of Xcode, or embed the bezier path in a view and quick look the view.

Comment: That sadly appears to be the case. Bug filed with Apple